# Cannot get string values from a bson value

Tags: json, mongodb, go, bson

I am making a website project and I want to get seession from username in mongo database. I wrote a function which takes session uuid and outputs the session name. I get the session and can print a bson in command line. I am trying to get string and float values from bson or at least a json value from bson in mongo golang. Here is the code I wrote in golang and mongodb go driver:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type user struct {
    UserName string
    Password []byte
    First    string
    Last     string
    Role     string
}

type session struct {
    Id           bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Un           string        `json:"value"`
    LastActivity time.Time     `json:"value"`
    UUID         string        `json:"value"`
}
func main() {
    s := session{bson.NewObjectId(), "darkness", time.Now(), "1222"}
    insertSession(s)
    v := "1222"
    getSession(v)
}

func getSession(UUID string) {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb+srv://lise:lise@cluster0.eouve.mongodb.net/userDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    sessionDatabase := client.Database("userDatabase")
    sessionCollection := sessionDatabase.Collection("sessionCollection")

    var sess []bson.M

    filter, err := sessionCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"uuid": UUID})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(sess)

    //wantedSession := session{sessionMatched[0].un, sessionMatched[0].lastActivity, ,sessionMatched[0].uuid}
}
```

Comment: `Find` returns a cursor. You have to read from that cursor to get the data.

Comment: @Burak Serdar should I use cursor.next() for reading from the cursor or something else? (thx for your answer btw very helpful :) )

Comment: See example here: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@v1.4.1#Cursor.Next

Comment: I understand that how to get a cursor but I want to turn bson into string or json and get the only username of the session. How can I implement it. Thx for your answer btw

Answer (score 0):

The way find works is it returns a '*Cursor'; what you can do to further get data from this is iterate over the cursor and get the relevant data from it.

```
cur, err := coll.Find(ctx, bson.M{"uuid": UUID})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer cur.Close(context.TODO())
for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
    var result bson.M
    err := cur.Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

if the Find query is returning only a single value with simple script followed by marshalling would do, as follows:

```
 cur.Next(context.TODO())
 var result bson.M
 err := cur.Decode(&result)
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
 }
```

Comment: I understand that how to get a cursor but I want to turn bson into string or json and get the only username of the session. How can I implement it. Thx for your answer btw

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main() {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    m := bson.M{"foo": "bar", "hello": "world", "pi": 3.14159}
    a := bson.A{"bar", "world", 3.14159, bson.D{{"qux", 12345}}}
    encoder.Encode(m)
    encoder.Encode(a)

    d := bson.D{{"foo", "bar"}, {"hello", "world"}, {"pi", 3.14159}}
    data := new(bytes.Buffer)
    json.NewEncoder(data).Encode(d)
    fmt.Println(data)

    var bT = struct {
        Foo string "bson:foo"
    }{}
    doc, _ := bson.Marshal(m)
    bson.Unmarshal(doc, &bT)
    fmt.Println(bT.Foo)
}
```

[`Example`](https://go.dev/play/p/ZyJtdL21rm6)